# Loop through table, use conditionals, then store value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The procedure is to fill the "City" column in Table B based on the "Letter" column from Table A.

**TABLE A**

```
+----------+-------+  
|  Number  | Letter|  
+----------+-------+  
| 1        |   A   |  
| 1        |       |  
| 1        |       |  
| 2        |       |  
| 2        |       |  
| 3        |       |  
| 3        |   B   |
| 3        |       |
| 3        |   C   |  
+----------+-------+
```

**TABLE B**

```
+----------+-------+  
|    AC    |  City |  
+----------+-------+  
| 1        |   A   |  
| 1        |   A   |  
| 1        |   A   |  
| 1        |   A   |  
| 2        |       |  
| 2        |       |  
| 2        |       |  
| 2        |       |  
| 3        |   B   |  
| 3        |   B   |  
| 3        |   B   |  
+----------+-------+
```

If AC=1, refer to Number=1, and loop through the "Letter" values from top to bottom to get the top-most value.

For Number=1, the topmost value is A, so for AC=1, fill in all "City" column as A.

For AC=2, Number=2, and there are no values in Table A, so fill in all "City" for each AC=2 as blank.

For AC=3, Number=3, and the top-most value is B, so fill in all "City" for each AC=3 as B.

How do you code this in standard SQL?

I am using the Caspio software and will be inserting the SQL into the "City" column itself, but that shouldn't interfere too much with the code.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Letter
FROM TableA 
WHERE TableA.Number = TableB.AC
AND TableA.Number != ""
LIMIT 1
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, and I think it's necessary to loop through Table A to find the City value for each AC=Number.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

I have figured out the solution:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Letter
FROM TableA
WHERE Letter !='' AND Number=AC
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (Btw: your example SQL is **not** "standard  SQL")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Caspio Bridge's back-end is built on Microsoft's .NET framework and Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Which version of MSSQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work because you are not including tableB in your FROM clause, or joining it. You can try this one:

```
    SELECT Letter FROM TableA WHERE Number IN 
(SELECT AC FROM TableB WHERE City!='' AND City IS NOT NULL)
AND Letter!='' AND LETTER IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But City column can be blank, if in Table A the rows are blank.

Comment: note also that TableA can have multiple Letters for the same number

Answer (score 0):

First things first, don't think of "looping" in SQL, it means that you're thinking about the problem wrong. You can to use set-based thinking.

So think about what you want to do, not how you want to do it.

You want to `update the TableB.City based on the value of TableA.Letter`

```
UPDATE TableB
SET City = Letter
FROM
(
    SELECT Number, Letter,ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY Number order by number ) AS SortOrder
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Letter IS NOT NULL AND Letter != ''
) AS A
WHERE A.SortOrder = 1 AND TableB.AC = A.number
```

I have included the `Row_Number` sorting, this is to ensure you get the first letter. Please note that you should order by your PK, assuming you have one and assuming that it's an `IDENTITY` and an `int`

See the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7105c/2)

**EDIT**
Sure, you can just do a select.

```
SELECT TableB.AC, A.Letter
FROM
(
    SELECT Number, Letter,ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY Number order by number ) AS SortOrder
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Letter IS NOT NULL AND Letter != ''
) AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB.AC = A.number
WHERE A.SortOrder = 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But is there a way to do this without "UPDATE"? Caspio doesn't support UPDATE for security reasons.

Comment: @user3313955 of course, you can't "store value in another table" if you don't have `update` privileges.

Comment: I put the edited code into sqlFiddle, but I am receiving an error. I will be putting the code directly into the City column in Caspio, so the result has to be the City value. I noticed your edited code has "SELECT TableB.AC, A.Letter" but I only need the Letter value for the City column.

Comment: @user3313955, a) you need to tell me what error you are getting in order for me to help, b) don't you need the Number or the AC in order to assign it properly? If you don't, then just get rid of `TableB.AC,` and run your `select`

Comment: Nevermind, I have the solution. SELECT TOP 1 Letter
FROM TableA
WHERE Letter !='' AND Number=AC